# how to write the leading superscript and subscript in Markdown syntax?

Tags: markdown, superscript

image: description of a coordinate transformation

[image]

I wonder how to write the leading superscript and subscript shown in the picture in Markdown syntax?

Comment: Too broad: You need to explain how you are rendering your Markdown: as **HTML**, as **PDF**, as **NSAttributedString** (iOS), etc. And what are the base rules that you are applying: **GitHub-flavored**, **BitbucketServer Markup**, **StackOverflow Markup**, **MultiMarkdown**, **CommonMark**, **Kramdown**, etc. You can find [a list of Markups variations here](https://github.com/laptobbe/TSMarkdownParser/blob/3.x/ROADMAP.md)

Answer (score 6):

Pandoc's flavor of markdown supports a [math extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math):

> Anything between two $ characters will be treated as TeX math.

The following string returns your desired output: `$_B^AR$`

Pandoc's markdown also has a [superscript and subscript extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#superscripts-and-subscripts):

> Superscripts may be written by surrounding the superscripted text by ^ characters; subscripts may be written by surrounding the subscripted text by ~ characters. Thus, for example,
>
> H~2~O is a liquid.  2^10^ is 1024.

But, as far as I know, there is no support for your request, a character that combines both a subscript and a superscript.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways of adding superscript and subscript to a Markdown doc:

- Use embedded HTML, such as the `<sup></sup>` and `<sub></sub>` tags, or even something like `<span style="vertical-align: super; font-size: medium;">` if you want more control.
- Use Unicode for some things, like numbers (`¹`, `²`) and some symbols (`™`, `℠`). See this [list of characters](https://gist.github.com/molomby/9bc092e4a125f529ae362de7e46e8176).
- Embed an image with the exact rendering you want using the `![alt text](image src)` syntax ([like this](https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#images-1)).
- Embed LaTeX directly in the Markdown doc using `$` or `$$` blocks. Eg. `Water, also known as H$_2$O`. See the raw version of [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/molomby/671bf5225274d34bd1297534598fd52d).

The first three options should work most places that use Markdown. LaTeX support isn't as widespread. For example [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#latex-macros) and [GitHub](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-05-19-render-mathematical-expressions-in-markdown/) now support it but StackOverflow and many other renderers don't.

I've described these options in more detail in my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51892162/762028).

Answer (score 4):

Try using `<sup></sup>` (`<sub></sub>`), as suggested in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155778/superscript-in-markdown-github-flavored)
(but indeed, the solution depends on the way it's rendered)

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing? Are you using Github or compiling a markdown file to pdf? Or using Jekyll? In any case you can display that (and any other math symbol) using latex inside markdown.

- If you are using Github: No idea how to do it
- If you are blogging using Jekyll: Use MathJax
- If you want to compile the markdown file to pdf: Use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)! just compile the file using: **pandoc test.md -o test.pdf**

In latex you can write leading superscripts with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
^gp = {}^gR^l_l+{}^go_l
\]
\end{document}
```

as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30554/superscripts-before-a-letter-in-math).